# Calculate difference between first and last result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a table with two columns. The first one ("val") is a integer, the second a timestamp ("ts").

Now I want to calculate the difference between the first and the last value of a given timespan.

```
SELECT MAX(val) - MIN(val) AS difference WHERE ts >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND ts <= '2015-01-07 23:59:59'
```

This one is not sufficient, because in the course of time the values can exceed/undercut the first and the last value.

Example:
Day 1: 100
Day 2: 120
Day 3: 110
Day 4: 98
Day 5: 105
Day 6: 112
Day 7: 110

The difference is 110 (Day 7) minus 100 (Day 1) = 10. Not Max(val) = 120 minus Min(val) = 98 = 22

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join to a subquery that returns the first and last *dates* and join using those, and use some simple arithmetic to calculate the difference using `sum()`:

```
select sum(val * case ts when ts1 then -1 else 1 end) diff
from data
join (select min(ts) ts1, max(ts) ts2
      from data
      where ts between ? and ?) x
on ts in (ts1, ts2)
```

See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b0389/2) (demo schema has been simplified to isolate the essence of the solution).

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use two subqueries, one that gets the first value and one that gets the last value:

```
SELECT ((SELECT val
         FROM table t
         WHERE ts >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND ts <= '2015-01-07 23:59:59'
         ORDER BY val DESC
         LIMIT 1
        ) - 
        (SELECT val
         FROM table t
         WHERE ts >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND ts <= '2015-01-07 23:59:59'
         ORDER BY val ASC
         LIMIT 1
        )
       ) as difference
```